# Rmarkdown html matrix output width too narrow

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I'm aware of the existing options to make output wider :

```
option(width=200)
```

The issue is when using `rmarkdown` to go straight from an **`R file`** to **`html`**, the output is bounded by the size of the html box, not the predetermined R option for line width.

What is the CSS option or something similar I could change to get a wider output box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the max-width property of .main-container. The default bootstrap theme sets it to 940px. You can change it by adding something like this to the top of your Rmd file:

```
<style type="text/css">

.main-container {
  max-width: 1280px;
}

</style>
```